# linking a image to words in a list

Tags: python, list, image, kivy, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import image
list = ["1","2","3"]
list[0] = Image.open("1.png")
```

This is what I tried so far make a "word" from a list have a image attached to it. I want to have a kivy button background that is decided by a random word from the list, I think I'm in the right path but it ain't working the way I want to.

Comment: What were you hoping to get as a result?

Comment: When I write something like background_normal  = "1" or background_normal  = "list[0]", the image has to be the background